# Zero padding in Matlab

Tags: matlab, padding, zero

I have image, and I want to do up sampling. First of all I need to plug zeros between pixels such that [1,2,3] transforms to [1,0,2,0,3]. Can anyone tell me how to do it without using `paddarray` and without using `for` loops?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
B=zeros(size(img)*2);
B(1:2:end,1:2:end)=img;
```

However there are ways of up-sampling in matlab without having the need of doing it by hand, for example [`interp2`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)

Comment: It is sort of Homework so I can't use any Image Processing toolboxes. But you answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: This is what I believe the OP is after too.  +1.

Answer (score 4):

You could also make use of MATLAB's way of dynamically allocating variables if you don't specify a number for an index into the array.  By omitting indexing into certain locations in your array, MATLAB will fill in these values with zeroes by default.  As such:

```
B(1:2:5) = 1:3

B = 

1   0   2   0   3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
V = [1,2,3];

padded(numel(V)*2) = 0;
padded(1:2:end) = V
```

And then just deal with the trailing zero if `numel(V)` was odd

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `upsample` that does exactly this from Octave-Forge -- see [docs on upsample](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/upsample.html).

Or you can look at [the source of `upsample`](http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/signal/ci/default/tree/inst/upsample.m) to see what implements it.  Are you opposed to using a package or a function?

Comment: Whoops; sorry. Source explicitly says incompatible with MATLAB. I guess you'll just have to switch to Octave to solve your problem ;-)

Comment: The OP doesn't have to switch to Octave ;). There are some perfectly acceptable answers here.

Comment: @rayryeng -- Clearly, OP does not have to switch. That was the purpose of my wink-smiley, to indicate joke/sarcasm. ;-) All four of these answers were posted within minutes of each other, and I upvoted a different (better!) answer when I saw it. My answer was intending as a reference to teach OP or others "to fish" -- Octave-Forge is a great resource, much of which is compatible with MATLAB. And, by happenstance, compatible with OP's "sort of Homework" intent. Someone's down-vote seems to indicate disagreement with my approach, but I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Couldn't agree more with you there!.. And I also winked to joke as well :). I use Octave when MATLAB isn't around. I didn't down vote you though. It's a valid approach!

Comment: @rayryeng -- indeed, I agree we're in agreement. I didn't say *you* downvoted, but *someone* did. :) Disagreement is valid and beneficial around here, also; for example, *I* use *MATLAB* when *Octave* isn't around. ;-) So muches of smileys!!1! :-D